# How to practically find the RA-DEC coordinates of a star?

Tags: astronomy, observational-astronomy

How are RA-DEC (Right Ascension & Declination) coordinates of a star measured i.e. if scientist spot a new star in the sky how do they accurately measure it's coordinates?

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

1. Many telescopes have computerised mounts, which once calibrated, will provide a direct readout of the RA and DEC of where the telescope is pointed
2. Another method is to take a photo (typically via a CCD) of the unknown star, and identify stars around the new object. Then look up the RA and DEC of the known stars, and then interpolate to find the RA and DEC of the one you want to determine.  There is software to do this.

Comment: Option 3: Measure the azimuth and altitude of the star using a compass and sextant and note the current time, date, latitude, and longitude. These can be converted to RA and Dec, either by hand with some complicated trigonometry or with a program like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24581-convert-azimuth-and-elevation-to-right-ascension-and-declination).

Comment: @dgh - I should perhaps have said that this was not an exhaustive list